# "mailto:"-link conversion tracking with Google Analytics via an e-mail forwarding service

Tags: email, google-analytics, web-analytics, email-forwarding

I would like to make a test scenario with Google Analytics and "mailto:"-Conversion Tracking or better explained, I want to track how many inquiries have i really received via a website.

The common way of tracking clicks on a "mailto:"-Link is to use **"onmousedown" or "onclick"** functions.

e.g.
    info@domain1.com
    info@domain1.com

The fear that I have is, that more and more crawlers, scripts, spambots,... will execute the onclick / onmousedown commands. Additionally not every visitor who is clicking on an e-mail address is also sending us an e-mail. After the "new message" windows is opened, our tracking usually stops. What I want to verify is, how many users are really sending us an e-mail instead of tracking how many people click on an e-mail address.

The solution that I have in mind, without too much technical / development background is an "**e-mail forwarding solution**".

1. **inquiry@domain1.com** is **shown at the website domain1.com** as inquiry e-mail address.
2. **inquiry@domain1.com** is automatically **forwarding all e-mails to domain1@trackingurl.com**
3. **domain1@trackingurl.com is executing a Google Analytics event** (which is quite simple) and is **again forwarding** all e-mails to the real email address, we want to have the emails sent to (e.g.: **info@domain1.com**)

### Questions

- Is the "forwarding idea" a good one or are there any downsides?
- How would you solve that idea / issue?
- Is there any open-source solution available for the forwarding part (as the Google Analytics part is not that hard to develop)?
- Which email engine/framework and/or which programming language would you recommend to use here?

Comment: This is something you might not know about: you can use the + sign in the email and most email providers will treat those as the same email (eg. wusatiuk+123456@gmail.com will deliver the mail to wusatiuk@gmail.com account). So you can hide information inside the email address itself, and don't need to forward anything.

Comment: Thanks @robert-bak. This is one possible solution i already thought about. do you know if there is any opensource script / add-on for a mailserver available as I was not able to find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `mailto:` links from a tracking point of view is that they open in a separate program, so you cannot add tracking to the 'send ecent'.

Rather than having `mailto:` links, you could instead have an email contact form. Add a Google Analytics tracking on the form submit event.

Comment: thanks for the hint. we are also using forms and know how to track them, but visitors often tend to use an e-mail address instead of a standardized contact form. the idea is to track the incoming mails to a specific IMAP account somehow. mabye via forwarding or only via some kind of IMAP Stats.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be possible and even if it were you would not be able to see the funnel which is important to see an analyzing conversions.

You are best having a form and thank you page to be 100% accurate.

Comment: I am working on a possible solution right now, not that easy but i am sure it will be worth it. you can e.g. add a simple reference code to the subject headline e.g. [ref:123456], where "12" is campaignname, "34" is medium and "56" is source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with tracking a mailto link is that it doesn't ping a server, but the default or open email client on the operating system. Due to the email client like Outlook, Gmail, and Yahoo Mail not wanting to share this information it's difficult to capture it. I wrote an article showing a few workarounds with [how to track mailto links](http://pidapi.com/how-to-track-mailto-links/).

You can also use Google Tag manager. Here's a video on it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5XDcH1tNm0